# python 3, OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:

Tags: python, qtablewidget

I'm having problem saving data from qtablewidget into excel

```
def save(self):        
    path = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self.tableWidget_2,'Save File', '', 'CSV(*.csv)')
    #if not path.isEmpty():

    with open(str(path), 'wb') as stream:
        writer = csv.writer(stream)
        for row in range(self.tableWidget_2.rowCount()):
            rowdata = []
            for column in range(self.tableWidget_2.columnCount()):
                item = self.tableWidget_2.item(row, column)
                if item is not None:
                    rowdata.append(str(item.text()).encode('utf8'))
                else:
                    rowdata.append('')
            writer.writerow(rowdata)
```

I got this traceback error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:\Users\Warren\Desktop\new interface\code\create_summary.py", line 60, in save
>      with open(str(path), 'wb') as stream:
>   OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "('C:/Users/Warren/Desktop/new interface/code/dsdsd.csv', 'CSV(*.csv)')"

How to fix this?

Comment: What exactly is `str(path)`?

Answer (score 0):

Just unpack the result from `getSaveFilename`:

```
path, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self.tableWidget_2,'Save File', '', 'CSV(*.csv)')
```